# Netbeans 8.0 - import older projects

Tags: netbeans

Newly installed Netbeans 8.0 does not recognize my projects previously build in Netbeans v6.9.1. How do you import these?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have old projects in some folder?

1. Copy this projects to C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects
2. In Netbeans File/Open Project
3. Select your project

Comment: I tried moving the entire project folder there, there is no project file in there that it recognizes. Just says "unrecognized project;missing plug-in"

Comment: Are you sure that save old projects?  Do you still have Netbeans 6.9 installed? These projects work there?

Comment: Appreciate your responses, unfortunately I do not control of that here and v6.9 is no longer available.  I could just create a new project in v8, however I am not seeing the same options to create a web app with a WAR file as in previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've installed the NetBeans for Java SE without NetBeans for Java EE. You need the NetBeans for Java EE bundle ([second column from the left](https://netbeans.org/downloads/)) for all the web projects.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using Java EE in one project, PHP and Zend in another. These projects needed plugins to work. I went to

```
NetBeans -> File -> Open Project
```

and my projects were listed even though they didn't show up in the Projects file browser. Each project's name was

```
<unrecognized project; missing plug-in?>
```

so I went to

```
NetBeans -> Tools -> Plugins
```

there I installed PHP, Zend and Java EE. I restarted NetBeans and everything worked fine.

This thread was useful to me:

http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic17656.html

Answer (score 0):

Once, I tried to install the Java SE Download bundles for Netbeans ( Was like mistake in clicking the Download option) but I was suppose to go for Java EE. SO, I was facing problem to import my previous Java EE Netbeans Project since I was in JavaSE Environment. Maybe Importing plugins for Java EE /Web or few more configuration would work for
 that case but I was seriously stuck for a long time.

The Error was like :

```
<unrecognized project; missing plug-in?>
```

So, What I did was simply uninstalling Java SE Netbeans and installing Java EE one and my older project was easily imported. So, seriously you might need to care about the download bundles or the installed plugins but Netbeans is mostly good for importing / Exporting.